# How to reference GLM?

Tags: regression, reporting

Following the question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24516/interaction-of-categorical-and-continuous-variable-using-glm-in-spss), how to I refer to GLM in my project?

Just a recap:

GLM is a general model that includes a number of regression techniques. I have used it to test the main effects of IVs (continuous and categorical) on the DV and also the IV-IV interactive effect on the DV.

I am confused about whether I should just say that I used GLM for data analysis, or is there a specific method to mention with GLM (e.g. I used SSI in GLM for data analysis).

This is necessary (in my mind) because names of other statistical tests are precise (e.g. ANOVA). I know GLM is general but there has to be some way to communicate precise information on this technique.

Many thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Maybe you don't need to mention GLM at all. If you did e.g. linear regression of the DV on several covariates, and based on that regression's output performed Wald tests of particular hypotheses, then just say that. (In fact there are so many ways to use GLMs that you *need* to say that much, to be precise about what was actually done.) Citing the piece of software you used to do the fitting would be courteous, but for use of GLM-fitting software is unlikely to be a big issue.

Comment: Write something like: used linear model [omit "general"] with 2 fixed factors [name them] and one covariate [name]. The model included intercept, all main effects and these interactions [name them]. Type I SS was employed, with terms entering the model in the following order...

Comment: Definitely omit "general", this seems an unecessary edition to "linear regression" or "linear model" and mixes things up with generalized linear models (very different) - a confusion SPSS seems largely responsible for.