# Can ANCOVA disagree with multiple regression?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, ancova, confounding

I have 3 categorical variables (CVa, CVb, CVc) all 0 or 1. Two continuous variables (IV1, IV2) are confounding my observational study. The multiple regression

```
lm(DV ~ CVa + CVb + CVc + CVa:CVb + CVa:CVc + IV1 + IV2)
```

is showing great significance for CVa

```
              Estimate   Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  -1.414684   1.498886  -0.944  0.35233
CVa1         -0.841076   0.256946  -3.273  0.00255 **
CVb1         -0.413594   0.168753  -2.451  0.01990 * 
CVc1         -0.328669   0.183652  -1.790  0.08298 . 
IV1          -0.011768   0.006519  -1.805  0.08049 . 
IV2           0.487658   0.211015   2.311  0.02743 * 
CVa1:CVb1     0.321766   0.238869   1.347  0.18743   
CVa1:CVc1     0.741290   0.259402   2.858  0.00744 **
```

I thought that ANCOVA (between factor CVa) must also show significance, but

```
summary(aov(DV ~ CVa + CVb + CVc + CVa:CVb + CVa:CVc + IV1 + IV2))
```

is not showing any significance for CVa

```
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)   
CVa        1  0.368  0.3681   3.093 0.08817 . 
CVb        1  0.427  0.4275   3.593 0.06709 . 
CVc        1  0.015  0.0148   0.125 0.72629   
IV1        1  0.585  0.5849   4.916 0.03384 * 
IV2        1  0.693  0.6935   5.828 0.02166 * 
CVa:CVb    1  0.126  0.1262   1.061 0.31069   
CVa:CVc    1  0.972  0.9716   8.166 0.00744 **
Residuals 32  3.807  0.1190
```

Am I doing ANOVA instead of ANCOVA? If yes, how do I control for IV1, IV2 to get that F-value they usually report in papers?

Just in case, `lsmeans(m2,pairwise ~ CVa * CVb)` reports that main effect of CVa is significant when controlled for IV1, IV2

```
$`CVa:CVb pairwise differences`
               estimate        SE df  t.ratio p.value
0, 0 - 1, 0  0.47043119 0.1725208 32  2.72681 0.04807
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

summary(lm(...)) reports tests based on Type 3 SS
summary(aov(...)) reports based on Type 1 SS

T1 tests the variables in the order they are entered in the model, eg/
CVa
CVb|CVa
CVc|CVa,CVb
etc

T3 tests the variables effectively conditional on all other variables in the model, eg/
CVa|Cvb,CVc,etc
CVb|Cva,CVc,etc

This is why you are getting different test results. More information on partitioning sum of squares can be found in this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20455/4485), and how to get T3 out of aov() [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20003/4485)

Comment: Thank you very much. Both Ancova() and Ancova(,type=3) worked for me ;)