# Comparing models of different types of ANOVA - multiple comparisons?

Tags: anova, mixed-model, multiple-comparisons

Statistical semi-novice question:

Just following up [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/53432/can-ancova-disagree-with-multiple-regression), the fact that the three types of ANOVA exist with an unbalanced design, and that (presumably) you don't necessarily know a priori which one is suitable for your data (because, say, you do not know whether an interaction is present), my understanding is that a comparison between the types may be necessary.

Isn't this equivalent to stepwise regression - and therefore problematic?

I'm wondering whether a better approach for an unbalanced design would be to use a mixed model?

Comment: Type II sum of squares is a good approach.