# Null hypothesis for ANOVA for regression

Tags: regression, anova, linear-model, f-test

Context: I know the "classic" ANOVA framework: we have $n$ groups and $k$ measurements of a variable $X$ for each group. Let $µ_1$, $µ_2$, ..., $µ_n$ be the mean of $X$ in each group.

Hypothesis $H_0$: $µ_1 = µ_2 = ... = µ_n$
Hypothesis $H_1$: $\exists i,j, \rm{\ such\ that \ }µ_i \neq µ_j$

Based on the effective samples, we can compute the value of "$F$", which is finally bigger or smaller than a certain threshold (calculated with $k$, $n$, and for example $\alpha=5\%$). This allows us to reject or not reject $H_0$. This is the classic ANOVA.

---

I often read about "ANOVA for regression", for testing the linearity / the validity of a linear model, but the hypothesis $H_0$ is rarely clearly described.

**Question**: how can we use the framework described in the first paragraph (which is about testing whether $µ_1 = µ_2 = ... = µ_n$ or not) to test the relevance of a linear model? What is the $H_0$ hypothesis in this case?

Concrete example: let's say we want to show linearity between X and Y, here is some input data:

For $x_0 = 2$, we have 4 measurements $y_{0,0} = 3.12$, $y_{0,1} = 3.27$, $y_{0,2} = 3.45$, $y_{0,3} = 3.28$.

For $x_1 = 3$, we have 4 measurements $y_{1,0} = 4.15$, $y_{1,1} = 4.37$, $y_{1,2} = 4.01$, $y_{1,3} = 3.98$.

For $x_2 = 4$, we have 4 measurements $y_{2,0} = 5.35$, $y_{2,1} = 5.58$, $y_{2,2} = 5.11$, $y_{2,3} = 5.67$.

We can do a linear regression $y = a + bx$, find $a$, $b$, $R^2$, etc.

**But how to use "ANOVA for regression" in this example?**

Here an hypothesis like $H_0$: $µ_1 = µ_2 = µ_3$ does not make any sense.

Comment: What regression model are you using for this ANOVA?

Comment: @Dave In this example, a regression gives $y = 1.0738 x + 1.0571 + \epsilon$ with $R = 0.975$. My question is : what would be the hypothesis $H_0$ for this "ANOVA for regression"? Here an hypothesis (to reject or not reject) like $µ1=µ2=µ3$ (which is the classical $H_0$ given in all courses about ANOVA) doesn't make sense, do you see what I mean?

Comment: And what do you want to test with your ANOVA regression?

Comment: @Dave I want to test the relevance of a linear model for this data, but more precisely, I don't have the answer - it's the core of my question: what should be the precise $H_0$ in this context?

Comment: Have you ever seen the classical ANOVA written as a regression? (If you haven't, this is one of the cooler statistics lessons.)

Comment: @Dave I have read a few things about this, like https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/175246/why-is-anova-equivalent-to-linear-regression, but rarely, the relevant $H_0$ are explicit. In the context of my last example, with 3 groups of 4 measurements, could you explain the exact ANOVA $H_0$ hypothesis?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@Basj 's answer (to their own question) puts it into the mathematical context of ANOVA. Here is a much simpler version:

For simple linear regression, the null hypothesis for the ANOVA is that the regression model (fit line) is identical to a simpler model (horizontal line). In other words, the null hypothesis is that the slope is actually zero.

Also note that the term "linearity" is not really defined in the question or the answers, and can be misleading. There can be a very strong relationship between X and Y that is not linear.

Comment: Thanks! Let's say $H_0$ is "slope = 0", and that we are able to reject $H_0$, thanks to a calculation of the $F$ value. What is the conclusion then? Can we safely conclude that "there is evidence of a linear relationship between X and Y"? TL;DR: does a rejection of the hypothesis "slope = 0" really give good statistical evidence of linearity between X and Y?

Comment: PS: with my example (at the end of the question) with 3 * 4 measurements, what conclusion can give an application of the ANOVA for regression method?

Comment: Linear regression *assumes* linearity and asks: Which line? If the p-value is small and you reject the null hypothesis that the slope is horizontal, the conclusion is that the slope is not horizontal.

Comment: Thanks @HarveyMotulsky. Is there a similar tool like F-test, etc. to test or reject linearity of a list of (x_i, y_i) values?

Comment: Do you think @HarveyMotulsky that my understanding here is correct https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/629735/102252? Thanks!

Comment: @Basj  I'm not sure what you mean by "linearity". There can be a very strong relationship between X and Y that is not linear. If you have replicate measurements at each X, there are tests for nonlinearity that test the null hypothesis that the relationship is a straight line. Is that what you are asking about?

Comment: Yes @HarveyMotulsky, exactly this.

Comment: This answer gives basically zero sense of why this is called ANOVA. I find that problematic.

Answer (score 4):

The typical place where students first hear the term "ANOVA: Analysis of Variance" is when the class extends the two-sample t-test to many samples (three, four, a zillion) and learn to test this with an F-test instead of a t-test.

What's happening under the hood is that this classical ANOVA is a regression model. Fix one of the groups as the baseline category which will be subsumed by the intercept (your choice won't affect the p-value or F-stat). Next, test if any of the other groups have a mean different from this baseline group. This is tested by checking if any of the coefficients on the indicator variables for the non-baseline groups are significantly different from zero, using an F-test of nested regression models: an intercept-only model that assumes all means to be equal is nested within a model that has an additional coefficient parameter for each non-baseline group that allows any of those groups to have a different mean.

For three groups, the regression model would be written as:

$$
\mathbb E\left[
y_i
\right] = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{i, \text{group1}} + \beta_2x_{i, \text{group2}}
$$

For $k$ groups, the regression model is:

$$
\mathbb E\left[
y_i
\right] = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{i, \text{group1}} + \beta_2x_{i, \text{group2}} +\dots  + \beta_{k - 1}x_{k-1, \text{group }k-1} 
$$

Where this gets extended to the full linear model (and beyond) is that none of this made any real assumptions about what the $x$ features are. Therefore, if you have three variables and want to check if two of them have nonzero coefficients, you might run regressions like the following.

$$
\mathbb E\left[
y_i
\right] = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{i, 1}\\
\text{nested within}\\
\mathbb E\left[
y_i
\right] = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{i, 1} + \beta_2x_{i, 2} + \beta_3x_{i, 3}
$$

Running an F-test of these nested models (exactly what we do in the basic ANOVA to test the equality of $k$ means) means that we are testing the following null and alternative hypotheses.

$$
H_0\text{: } \beta_2 = \beta_3 = 0\\
H_a\text{: } H_0 \text{ is false (at least one of }\beta_2\text{ and }\beta_3\text{ are nonzero)}
$$

When you dig into the math, you'll see that this relates to comparing the residual variance from the simple model to the residual variance from the complex model in which the simple model is nested, hence the term *analysis of variance*.

In your specific example, you have a simple linear regression. If you want to test if the slope is nonzero, your F-test would compare the simple linear regression with both a slope and an intercept to a model with just an intercept. When you do an F-test on just one parameter, that is equivalent to a t-test on that one parameter.

The F-test winds up being much more general than just comparing the means of $k$ groups!

**RELATED CROSS VALIDATED LINKS**

[Why is ANOVA equivalent to linear regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/175246/why-is-anova-equivalent-to-linear-regression)

[What's the difference between regression and analysis of variance?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/268006/whats-the-difference-between-regression-and-analysis-of-variance)

[What are chunk tests?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27429/what-are-chunk-tests)

I personally learned this material from a course that used Alan Agresti's *Foundations of Linear and Generalized Linear Models*. Section $3.2.1$ develops basic ANOVA as a regression model, and then $3.3.2$ develops the general "chunk" test. (For years, I have kept that book near where I work, either at my desk at the office or near my workspace at home.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't understand the big picture (I'm coming with a math background, but not stats at all). Isn't there a way to show the $H_0$ in my question's simple concrete example, without these "nested" $E[y_i]=...$? Why would there be multiple `E[yi]=β0+β1xi,group1+β2xi,group2`? In my simple example, there should be only one model $y_i = a + b x_i$. Indeed "group 1" is here the points for $x_0 = 2$, "group 2" is the 4 points for $x_0 = 3$, "group 3" is the points for $x_0 = 4$, nothing else than this. Is there a simpler way to present the ANOVA for regression in this case?

Comment: @Basj You have four groups. If the mean of one of them fails to differ from the mean of each of the other three, that means the four groups have equal means, correct? Likewise, if that group has a mean different from the mean of any of the other three groups, then the four means are not equal, agreed?

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain?

Answer (score 4):

One Anova test for regression that has not been mentioned yet is the full-reduced model test.  This can be interpreted as a test of linearity where you are comparing a straight line relationship to a non-linear relationship.

The full-reduced model test is very general for testing any case where we have a more complex model (the full model) and a reduced model (a simpler case) and the reduced model is "nested" in the full model, i.e. all the terms in the reduced model are also in the full model.  Though the idea of nesting can be flexible in that the terms do not need to be in the exact same format (e.g. an x variable that is centered and scaled in one model, but not the other still counts).

For testing linearity the full model would have multiple terms to fit a non-linear curve between $x$ and $y$.  This could be a polynomial expansion on $x$ or just the traditional analysis of variance method of fitting a mean for each unique value of $x$.  The reduced model then has the linear relationship (regression) between $x$ and $y$.

The null hypothesis is that the 2 models fit equally well (the full model does not fit any better than the reduced model) and the alternative hypothesis is that the additional terms in the full model to have a significant contribution.  In some model formulations the null hypothesis can be expressed in terms of coefficients equaling 0, e.g. all the non-linear polynomial coefficients if using a polynomial expansion.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the other answers, and external readings, such as [How to Interpret the F-test of Overall Significance in Regression Analysis](https://statisticsbyjim.com/regression/interpret-f-test-overall-significance-regression/), and [A Simple Guide to Understanding the F-Test of Overall Significance in Regression](https://www.statology.org/a-simple-guide-to-understanding-the-f-test-of-overall-significance-in-regression/)
, [The Analysis of Variance (ANOVA) table and the F-test](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat462/node/107/), here is how I now understand this example:

> Let's say we want to show linearity between X and Y, here is some input data:
> For $x_0 = 2$, we have 4 measurements $y_{0,0} = 3.12$, $y_{0,1} = 3.27$, $y_{0,2} = 3.45$, $y_{0,3} = 3.28$.
> For $x_1 = 3$, we have 4 measurements $y_{1,0} = 4.15$, $y_{1,1} = 4.37$, $y_{1,2} = 4.01$, $y_{1,3} = 3.98$.
> For $x_2 = 4$, we have 4 measurements $y_{2,0} = 5.35$, $y_{2,1} = 5.58$, $y_{2,2} = 5.11$, $y_{2,3} = 5.67$.

First, the hypotheses:

Null hypothesis (H0) : The model with no predictor variables (also known as an intercept-only model) fits the data as well as the regression model.

Alternative hypothesis (H1) : The regression model fits the data better than the intercept-only model.

Least squares give: `y = 1.0571 + 1.0738 x`

```
                      df     SS           MS                   F
Regression            1      SSR          MSR = SSR / 1        F = MSR / MSE = 194.2
Residual              10     SSE          MSE = SSE / (n-2)
Total                 11     SST
```

In the table [https://www.stat.purdue.edu/~lfindsen/stat503/F_alpha_05.pdf](https://www.stat.purdue.edu/%7Elfindsen/stat503/F_alpha_05.pdf), we can see that F > 4.965, thus we reject $H_0$.

Comment: It will help (at least in the long run) for you to write your null and alternative hypotheses with equations.

Comment: You're missing the connection to the classical ANOVA, which I think is one of the key points of statistics. // What do you think the null and alternative hypotheses are? Does my answer give any idea?

Comment: $1)$ The connection to the classical ANOVA is the subject of the answer I posted. $//$ $2)$ What are the explicit null and alternative in terms of the regression parameters?

Comment: What does it say about the regression parameters if the model fits just as well as an intercept-only model that is nested within it? Perhaps look at the hypotheses in the answer I posted.